# Ajax call succesfull, second ajax call is send twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

With an AJAX call, I post a the value of a textarea to my database. The first post is always correct. But after I try to post another post, the AJAX call is executed twice. If I post again after that, the AJAX call is executed 4 times. It grows exponentially.

Here's my code:

```
$(".comment-box").on("keydown", function(e) {
    e = e || event;
    if (e.keyCode === 13 && !e.shiftKey) {
        var message = $(".comment-box").val();
        var id = $(".comment-box").attr("data-id");

        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: "../assets/js/ajax/comment-to-screen.php",
            data: { 
                'message': message, 
                'id': id 
            },
            success: function (data) {
                $(".comment-box").val('');
                $(".all-comments").append(data);
                init();
                return false;
            }
        });

        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

This is wrapped into a `init()` function,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    init();

    function init () {
        // Here is the code to post with ajax
    }
});
```

Comment: **Everytime** `init` function runs it binds a callback to `$(".comment-box").on("keydown" ..)` Despite the fact that all this callbacks are the same, they still execute after each other.

Comment: As said, it's because of the repeated calls to `init()`. If you're doing this to bind the `keydown` event to the newly appended elements, use event delegation instead.

Comment: Don't call `init()` from within the success callback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In every successful post callback, a call to init is made. Init then attaches *another* handler to the textbox.

The next time enter is pressed, the *two* event handlers fire... ans so on

I think you can just remove the init call from the success handler